# DynamoDB query using DynamoDBMapper

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Say if I had a DynamoDB table:

```
UserId (hash): S
BookName (range): S
BorrowedTime: S
ReturnedTime: S
```

UserId is the primary key (hash), and I needed to set BookName as sort key (range) because another item being added to the database was overwriting the previous with the same UserId.

How would I go about creating a query using DynamoDBMapper, but the fields being queried are the time fields (which are non-keys)? For instance, say if I wanted to return the UserId and BookName of any book borrowed over 2 weeks ago that hasn't been returned yet?

Do I need to setup a GSI on both BorrowedTime and ReturnedTime fields?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a GSI using BorrowedTime and ReturnedTime or you can use scan instead of a query , if you use scan you dont need to make a gsi but scan operations scan the whole database so it is not really recommended on large db or frequent use.

Comment: The table could have thousands of items - so probably a query is best. Should I be setting a GSI on both the time fields, or just one GSI with a partition and the other as a sort key? I'm not sure how this query would even look...

Comment: how is the data saved in borrowed time and returned time ?  you should only need one GSI

Comment: The table is currently being created, so whatever makes most sense. At the moment it’s a ISO datetime formatted string. ReturnTime can be changed to a boolean type if it makes more sense, but it’s currently datetime and field only gets added when book is returned (wasn’t sure whether to have the field added at the same time of creating the item then just null the ReturnTime, or avoid adding the field until there is a value there for it). Basically there is flexiblility there to do it correctly...

Comment: Also, if it is only one GSI, is the ReturnedTime the sort key then?

Comment: Actually maybe I just need the one GSI, and then set ProjectionType: "ALL"?